# Lost LXD/LXC with most recent 20.04 upgrade

Tags: 20.04, lxc, lxd

Ubuntu 20.04 update/upgrade broke lxd/lxc containers
History:
Ubuntu 16.04 Server running LXD upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and subsequently Ubuntu 20.04.
All LXC containers worked fine until yesterdays “update&upgrade”. Containers were set up as a file server, that directory cannot be found.
Can I walk this upgrade back?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `/etc/fstab` entry to mount your storage at `/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd` instead of `/var/lib/lxd`, and then reboot your system.